# Django 1.8 Admin Form: AttributeError XForm object has no attribute 'save_m2m'

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I'm trying to create a custom form for a model I have with an additional field in Django, but when I try to submit the form, I get the following error:

`AttributeError: 'UnitForm' object has no attribute 'save_m2m'`

This is particularly strange because I don't have a form named UnitForm.

my `forms.py` looks like

```
class UnitAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    time_changed = forms.SplitDateTimeField(widget=widgets.AdminSplitDateTime)

    class Meta:
        model = Unit
        fields = ['status','time_changed']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        changed_at = self.cleaned_data.get('time_changed', None)
        self.instance.status = self.cleaned_data['status']
        self.instance.save(changed_at=changed_at) #the changed_at part is handled on the model
        super(UnitAdminForm, self).save()
        return self.instance
```

and my `admin.py` looks like:

```
class UnitAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     form = UnitAdminForm
     list_display = ('__unicode__','status')
 admin.site.register(Unit, UnitAdmin)
```

It seems like the admin is creating a new class (UnitForm) that's a child of the class I provide, but I'm still unsure as to why this save_m2m method doesn't exist or how I should properly fix this error.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a `UnitForm` but you declare one in `UnitAdmin`. Try changing the  to UnitAdmin class to:

```
class UnitAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     form = UnitAdminForm
     list_display = ('__unicode__','status')
admin.site.register(Unit, UnitAdmin)
```

Edit: ok I guess that your problem is that you manually save and forgot to call save_m2m(), from the [django docs about save()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method):

> To work around this problem, every time you save a form using commit=False, Django adds a save_m2m() method to your ModelForm subclass. After you’ve manually saved the instance produced by the form, you can invoke save_m2m() to save the many-to-many form data.

Comment: This is a correct change, but it was because I copied in code from when I tried to see if the error was assuaged by renaming it to UnitForm. Sorry for putting in incorrect code.

Comment: Well shouldn't the form have this method to begin with? Calling self.save_m2m() returns the same error

Comment: Ok, let's see. The error is `AttributeError: 'UnitForm' object has no attribute 'save_m2m'` ? or `AttributeError: 'UnitAdminForm' object has no attribute 'save_m2m'` ?

Comment: It stays as UnitForm, but now where the traceback said
` File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1100, in save_related
    form.save_m2m()
AttributeError: 'UnitForm' object has no attribute 'save_m2m' `

it now says 

` File "/units/forms.py", line 10, in save
    self.save_m2m()
AttributeError: 'UnitForm' object has no attribute 'save_m2m'`

Comment: That's the thing, UnitForm does not exist, it seems to be being created by Django

Comment: Ok, if you don't have UnitForm anywhere I have no clue... Sorry

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, and I managed to solve it by calling the super(), like so:

```
class UnitAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    time_changed = forms.SplitDateTimeField(widget=widgets.AdminSplitDateTime)

    class Meta:
        model = Unit
        fields = ['status','time_changed']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        self.instance.status = self.cleaned_data['status']
        self.instance.changed_at = self.cleaned_data['time_changed']
        # dont call the .save() here
        # self.instance.save(changed_at=changed_at)

        # change return statement to this
        return super().save(commit=commit)
```

I hope this helps